# Spotify API 1.0.0: addToCollectionButton not working

Tags: spotify, playlist

Has anyone got the addToCollectionButton working?

```
var album = models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:37uqAKt9dLsLob7yomDWY4');
var button = buttons.AddToCollectionButton.forItem(album);
document.getElementById('AddToCollectionButton').appendChild(button.node);
```

This adds a green button with plus sign, so far so good.
But when I click it, it doesn't do anything.

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The AddToCollection button is related to the Collection feature, [presented in December last year](http://www.theverge.com/2012/12/6/3736018/spotify-debuts-new-discovery-engine-collection-and-follow-which-lets). So at this point in time it's not the correct button for what you want to do.

If you want to add an album to a user's playlist, you could create a [button](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/buttons-button.html) that adds that album as a playlist to the user's library. The [SubscribeButton](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/buttons-subscribebutton.html) can be used if you want a button that lets the user subscribe/follow a playlist (among other things).